# Latest Android Studio, and App does not work; shows blank

Tags: android

I have just updated to the latest Android Studio (2.3.1) and when I run my app, it doesn't work - I am supposed to see a ListView with text within, but I only see a blank white screen.

I am working on the Udacity introduction to android programming, so I do not know much. If it helps, I am at the beginning of lesson-3.

Logcat shows this:
28860-28860 W: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.sunshine.app-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.sunshine.app-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status

Update--------

Through some debugging, I might have narrowed down the issue within the following code in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

The getSupportFragmentManager method is not even recognised and shows up as red. I had to previously change the import statements to get pieces of code to work.

Comment: this does not look like logcat quote for me but rather gradle console/log. Look in Logcat

Comment: I checked again. This is clearly from the logcat within the Android Monitor. If you are instead referring to the tab at the bottom that says "Terminal," it is not from that.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you haven't assigned an ID to your ListView.

**Add an ID like this..**

```
<ListView
      android:id="@+id/listView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

If that doesnt work try clean building the broject by clicking **Build > Clean project**

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I checked and all the IDs are accounted for and seem to be correct.